# Java/JUnit - track every passed and failed method

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm looking into incorporating detailed report generation for selenium tests. What I want to achieve is something similar to reports produced by robot-framework, namely: each method which is called during test execution provides information whether it succeeded or failed.

so, if the test method is:

```
@Test
public void sampleTest() {
  LoginToApp.logInAsAdmin();
  Tree.selectOnTree("something");
  Misc.takeScreenshot("file.png");
}
```

logInAsAdmin() calls some other methods:

```
public static void logInAsAdmin() {
  logIn(getAdminUserName(), getAdminPass());
  Click.clickElementByTestId("test");
}
```

selectOnTree() also:

```
public static void selectOnTree(String elementId) {
  findPathToElement(elementId);
  Click.clickElementByTestId(elementId);
}
```

and, for example, test fails on clicking tree item (thus, clickElementByTestId() in selectOnTree() failed). I want to obtain nice report with all executed methods, provide information which method called it (hierarchy of calls is important). sth like:

```
sampleTest - FAILED
  logInAsAdmin - PASSED
    logIn - PASSED
    clickElementByTestId - PASSED
  selectOnTree - FAILED
    findPathToElement - PASSED
    clickElementByTestId - FAILED
```

Using TestWatcher from JUnit isn't enough, as it only provides name of the test method failed, and no information about subsequent method calls. One simple, but inconvenient way to do it, is simply modify each method to send it's 'execution status' to some kind of reporter. Are there any other, more elegant ways to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (aspect oriented programming) to be the answer to the question. With the use of i.e. [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) it is possible to 'intercept' every method call, get it's name, parameters etc. without code obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar by implementing the WebDriverEventListener interface from org.openqa.selenium.support.events

There is a list of methods where you can put printing the necessary information

```
 public class MyWebDriverEventListener implements WebDriverEventListener {

     public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void afterNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void afterScript(String script, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void beforeScript(String script, WebDriver selenium) {}
     public void onException(Throwable error, WebDriver selenium) {}
 }
```

See more details [here](http://blog.simon-reekie.me/2011/05/21/logging-selenium-2-events-in-twist/).